# Unity Анимации как запустить через Animation

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не пойму как по скрипту по нажатию на кнопку заставить играть ту или иную анимацию, помогите добрые люди. Анимации находятся в массиве в Animation. Пытался обращаться через anim.Play("walk"). Не помогло выдавало ошибку. Кто сталкивался подскажите как разобраться пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для анимаций персонажа нужен не `Animation`, а `Animator`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно правильно настроит Animator компонент. Который входит в стандартный инструмент игрового движка.

Вот легкий пример, взятый из официальной документации unity:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (anim != null)
            {
                // play Bounce but start at a quarter of the way though
                anim.Play("Base Layer.Bounce", 0, 0.25f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Более подробно об аниматоре вы можете ознакомится самостоятельно, перейдя по ссылке [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html)

Comment: Спасибо, действительно без аниматора никак)